# Need help figuring out out to display an error message if something doesnt match my query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Question is I have a query that looks at my emp_id text box once something is typed in it searches for the information tied to that emp_id which in my other table that it searches for its called ID.. If the emp_id matches the id in my visual model it will populate their first name for them. I would like to know how I can get it to display an error if no emp_id matches an id in my visual model....

This is what I have so far but I keep getting a no method error....

This is the error

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `emp_matches' for #<Visual:0x00000005a4c8d8>):
  app/controllers/user_controller.rb:31:in `populate_form'
```

This is my user controller.

```
class UserController < ApplicationController


def populate_form

  @visual = Visual.find_by_id(params[:emp_id])
  @emp_first_name = @visual.first_name

  if @visual.emp_matches(@emp_id).id
    flash[:notice] = "Emp Id found"


    render :json => {

        :emp_first_name => @emp_first_name

    }
  else
    flash[:error] = "Emp ID not found"
  end
end
```

This is my visual model..

```
 class Visual < ActiveRecord::Base

 establish_connection :vtest

 self.table_name = 'employee'


 Visual.inheritance_column = 'inheritance_type'

 belongs_to :user

 def emp_matches?(x)
   (x.id.to_i == self.id.to_i ? true : false)
 end
end
```

And this is my view..

```
<div class='row form-group'>
   <div class='col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-5 text-right'>
    <%= f.text_field :emp_id, tabindex: 1, id: 'emp_id', autofocus: true, placeholder: t( 'login_label' ), class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
</div>

 <div class='row form-group'>
  <div class='col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-5 text-right'>
    <%= f.text_field :emp_first_name, tabindex: 1, id: 'emp_first_name', autofocus: true, placeholder: t( 'login_label' ), class: 'form-control' %>
   </div>
 </div>
```

My tables

Visual model

```
      Table is called Employee 
        ID
        emp_first_name
```

User model

```
      Table is called User 


        emp_id
```

Fixed my question mark error...

```
 def emp_matches(x)
   (x.id.to_i == self.id.to_i ? true : false)
 end
end
```

but I am still getting no method error

```
 NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):
 app/models/visual.rb:18:in `emp_matches'
  app/controllers/user_controller.rb:31:in `populate_form'
```

Comment: You've defined your method as `emp_matches?` but you're invoking it as `@visual.emp_matches(@emp_id)` without the question mark.

Comment: Updated my question after I fixed the ? mark  I am still getting nomethod error @PaulRichter

Comment: where does `@emp_id` get defined? You are getting a new noMethod error.   Since you are trying to the id of a nil value.

Comment: As Doon said, you're not setting up the `@emp_id` variable. To be honest, and I'm not trying to be a jerk here, but this is really basic debugging that doesn't belong in an SO question. If you're having some other issue beyond that, that's fine, but you really can't keep pasting each error consecutively in the comments without trying to solve it first (that nil was an easy one)

Comment: I figured it out it was because I was doing this (x.id.to_i == self.id.to_i ? true : false) but It should of been     (x.to_i == self.id.to_i ? true : false ) .. hahah sorry its been a long day thanks for the help though. @PaulRichter

Comment: @user3910236 Its all good, I just wouldn't want you to rob yourself of valuable learning and/or debugging experience. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are over complicating this, and based on the information provided I don't think we need to concern ourselves the `user` model.  you can do something like this

```
def populate_form

   visual = Visual.find_by_id(params[:emp_id])
   if visual 
    render :json => {
        :emp_first_name => visual.first_name
    }
  else
    render :json => { :error => 'not found' }
  end
end
```

Then your javascript can do something if it finds the emp_first_name in the json response, or the error.   I still don't see why the emp_matches part is needed?